# how to minify a static website using node

Tags: node.js, npm, build, minify, bundling-and-minification

I have a static website (index.html, folder for styles, scripts and media) and would like to have a script that minifys all files and puts them in a dist folder (keeping folder structure). I feel like that should be a common thing people do, yet I couldn't find any scripts or packages that do that.
I also started writing my own script (not polished)

```js
exec("mkdir dist", () => {
    [["script", "js"], ["style", "css"]].forEach(([folderName, flag]) => {
        exec(`mkdir .\\dist\\${folderName} & dir /b /a-d ${folderName}`, (_, res) => {
            res.split("\n").forEach(fileName => {
                if (!fileName) return;

                exec(`minify ${folderName}\\${fileName}`, (_, min) => {
                    fs.writeFile(`.\\dist\\${folderName}\\${fileName.trim()}`, min, { flag: 'w' }, err => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(fileName.trim(), err);
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Any Ideas what "the right way" to do this is?

Comment: Have you looked at [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/)?

Comment: @j-petty i feel like a bundler like webpack would be overkill since I only have a few script files all written by myself, no librarys

Comment: Well, you asked for the de-facto way and honestly I think using a bundler is the de-facto way right now. If webpack feels overwhelming, there's also bundlers like [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You should not write your own script.
There are many solutions out there for most of the problems we are facing with. 
[Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) is a great solution to what you are describing. 
**Webpack** takes you modules and dependencies and set them under the bundle.js file as static assets.